# django newbie - creating fixtures data from manually entered data

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have finally got my admin part of my django site working.

I am now beginning the tedious part of manually entering the initial data into the database. Obviously, I want this to be a one time affair.

Can anyone suggest to me how I can create fixtures data from my manually entered data, so that I can reload the data (automatically?) when I do a manage.py syncdb ?

Comment: Er, I think I fixed it - there was an error in my admin script. Can someone delete this question (I don't have enough points to delete it)

Comment: IGNORE THE COMMENT ABOVE.  Grrr!. This inability to delete questions is a real pain in the butt!. I have changed my question completely now, since I managed to fix it - so obviously, this is now an entirely different question.

Comment: Oops, already voted to close, and that can't be undone. Luckily you need five votes, so hopefully no-one else will vote for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`dumpdata` management command](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-appname-appname-appname-model).

```
python manage.py dumpdata yourappname > app_data.json
```

Comment: I did as you suggested, but I piped the output to appname/fixtures/myapp_data.json. When I run manage.py syncdb, it echoed "No fixtures found". So, I piped the dumped data to the project directory (like in your example), still, I got the same message: "No fixtures found". According to the docs, django looks in the app/fixtures folder (as part of its path), so its not clear what I'm doing wrong. Is there a specific command to load fixtures data?.

Comment: Sorry, slight misunderstanding. If you want the fixture to always be loaded on `syncdb`, you have to call it `initial_data.json`. See [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/).

Comment: Thanks very much. I have all the info I need now. Thanks once again!